# When writing a Qt application is good practice to ALWAYS prefer Qt function implementations, data types, and classes when they are available?

Tags: c++, programming-practices, ide, data-types, qt

I'm just starting out with Qt and I really want to try and keep my application as separated from Qt as possible in case I decide to use a different toolset later, but at the same time don't want to make any decisions that will really cripple my application right from the beginning.

When writing a Qt Application is it considered good practice to always prefer Qt implementations when they are available? Or in some situations is it best to stick with standard C++ even when Qt has an alternative?

Consider the following...

### Function implementations:

Should I always prefer to use a Qt function implementation when it is availabe? Take the math functions for example...

- `pow` vs `qPow`
- `log` vs `qLn`
- etc...

### Data types:

Should I always prefer Qt data types over the defaults?

- `int32_t` vs `qint32`
- `double` vs `qreal`
- etc...

### Objects:

Should I always prefer Qt objects over their STL equivalents?

- `std::string` vs `QString`
- `std::vector` vs `QVector`

---

In each of these situations what are the advantages/disadvantages. What will I gain or lose?

The more Qt based functions/objects I use the more difficult it would be to switch to something other than Qt later.

Comment: In my opinion it's not *always* a good practice, it just depends on your need, the design you have. But I prefer to stay consistent and use Qt classes when the code is already full of Qt that cannot be standard C++ anyway.

Comment: @ymoreau: I am starting a project fresh so I am free to choose. I am deciding to go with standard C++ until I encounter a situation where Qt seems to give me trouble and needs to use its own objects. :)

Comment: I meant if you have some needs that STL does not cover and you know you will use different Qt modules anyway, these modules will need some Qt types (QString, Qt containers, signal/slots stuff) and you might prefer to use Qt in the rest of your code than doing a lot of conversions, again depending on the design you have ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is an exact equivalent in the C++ standard (like for exact-width types, or math functions), you loose portability to any project not using QT, without gaining anything. And people might wonder what that function / type / whatever does or does differently if they are not intimately knowledgeable about QT.

There are two reasons for using QT object types like `QString` and `QVector`:

1. Independence from the C++ library you use. This is only an advantage if you expect it to have breaking changes more often than QT, and cannot / will not provide an update.
2. Adherence to the interface of functions you use.

Those two points apply in reverse to using the standard types instead.

Comment: If you really don't gain anything from using a Qt implementation of a function then why would the Qt versions exist in the first place? There has to be more to it than that.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Very often the reason the Qt versions even exist is simply because either they were made before the standard version was introduced.

Comment: @Teimpz, are there any circumstances where that isn't the case and the Qt function actually provides a real advantage over using the standard equivalent?

Comment: @tjwrona1992: Looking at the current QT docs, they marked a lot as deprecated because there is a standard version for quite a long time now. They haven't gotten rid of all the redundancy yet though...

Comment: @Deduplicator, what documentation are you looking at? I can't seem to find any Qt documentation that references functions as being deprecated. (I was looking at the QtMath documentation "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmath.html#qCos"

Comment: See the qt algorithm header: ["*Historically, Qt used to provide functions which were direct equivalents of many STL algorithmic functions. Starting with Qt 5.0, you are instead encouraged to use directly the implementations available in the STL; most of the Qt ones have been deprecated (although they are still available to keep the old code compiling).*"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html)

Comment: @Deduplicator, okay so those are clearly marked as obsolete, but if the Qt math functions didn't actually provide some special benefit it doesn't make sense that they would not be deprecated as well. It even looks like some of them were introduced in relatively recent versions of Qt where there was definitely already a standard version.

Comment: Well, chalk it up as the vagaries of design by committee. Admittedly the constants are nice to have, and the conversion functions probably too.

Comment: QString provides far more utility functions than the std::string counterpart. I guess it could be similar for other Qt classes.

Comment: @RandomGuy, I guess for now I will just code as much as possible as if it were standard C++, and then when I run into situations where the Qt variant provides more I will be forced to use that instead. It seems like the safest course of action for the time being.